# Trying to sort an array list of price in US currency, it's sorting ¢79 > $3.50

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, currency

I have the below array :

```
String Array = [$3.50 , $ 4.00, 79¢ , 90¢, $8.50] ;
```

How can we sort this array list for the output like

```
79¢ , 90¢ , $3.50, $4.00, $8.50
```

I also tried parsing it to remove the currency signs but that makes 79 > 3.50

thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share how you tried parsing it making 79 > 3.50?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following algorithm for your purpose:

1. Separates the numbers with the currency exchange mark with
   `Array.split()`.
2. Multiplies all values (by currency exchange rate) all by the same
       currency exchange rate.
3. Sorts the values.
4. Divide the values again to the same currency they were, each value
       to return to the same currency exchange rate that was.
5. Reconnects the icon of each currency.

It's a bit tricky and requires work, but possible, good luck!